# Trying to read a React state gives the initial state rather than the updated one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React function component that listens to a click of a button and changes a state accordingly.
I can see that the state indeed changed as reflated in the view. Yet, when trying to read the current state - it still seem to be the initial one:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("Not Changed");
  const [print, setPrint] = React.useState(null);

  const change = () => {
    setState("Changed!!!");
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setPrint(() => {
      return () => {
        console.warn("state > ", state); //=> "state >  Not Changed"
      };
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", marginBottom: "30px" }}>
        <button onClick={change}>Change State</button>
        <div>{state}</div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={print}>Print State</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also see the code working here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-lalande-x8w6p?file=/src/App.js

In the browser - I see the html updated to "Changed!!!". But in the console, I still see "state >  Not Changed" being printed.

I would really appreciate someone helping me picking up on what I am missing here. Thanks!

Comment: do you know what the second argument to `useEffect` is for? you're passing an empty array meaning that function will only have capture the values of state when the component mounts https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-the-useeffect-dependency-array-2913da504c44

Comment: Yes I do, actually. But I read that this is a common practice to make something run only once on mount . Isn't that so?

And still - why does  the reference to state points to the initial value?

Comment: the way you have written it, is the "effect" is setting your dispatcher callback with a state value "when it was mounted". if you want to update that effect with the new state value then you need to add `state` to your dependency array, which would make perfect sense based on the code you have `useEffect(..., [state])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass `state` to `useEffect`:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setPrint(() => {
      return () => {
        console.warn("state > ", state);
      };
    });
  }, [state]);
```

Comment: Thanks. That actually works. Now I am just trying to understand why. It's "state" a variable withing the scope of App? why would reading it here refers to the initial value?

Comment: If you don't pass it, useEffect works like componentDidMount.